# Spring Boot Oauth2 - Where is the access token stored?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, access-token, keycloak

I have a jhipster (spring boot and angular) project  implementing oauth2 protocol with Keycloak. I managed to get the application to redirect to keycloak for authentication. I am quite confused as to where the access token is in the response after sign in and where is it stored after redirecting back to my site? 
I tried using chrome inspect to view the network but I can't seem to find the access token.

Below is a link I used to setup oauth2 for my project:
https://www.jhipster.tech/security/

URL when login is clicked: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/oidc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the reply. Managed to get the tokens using the following:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) 
securityContext.getAuthentication();

OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService
            .loadAuthorizedClient(oauth2Token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), 
oauth2Token.getName());

refreshToken = client.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue();
```

Comment: What does clientService.loadAuthorizedClient do? It doesn't seem to be a class from Spring Secruity.

Comment: @vic Isn't it just @Autowired `private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;`?

Comment: hmm, seems like ClientRegistationId and userName isn't enough to generate OAuth2 Token, it works only on single request after OAuth2 Authorization succeeded

Answer (score 2):

With OAuth2, the authentication is stateful which means that you have a cookie (`JSESSIONID`) for the Spring session.

You can get more information by inspecting the context using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` in the backend.

Comment: Yes,  Right, Is it safe to put there, can we change this default behavior, can we use session(local http context) to store token at client side, is there website to learn more about it, can you explain full end to end process more briefly, i have lots of doubts, Thanks

Comment: `Stateful`( user state store at Server Side), `Stateless`(user state store at Client Side Not Server Side), cookies are at Client not Server, so its `Stateless`